# How to set up an optional arg in pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I wonder if there is any way in `\pgfkeys` of `tikz` to define optional arg(s) as the following code illustrate:

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt


\begin{document}
% #1 for optional args in the macro \includegraphics, "width=\linewidth", for example
% #2 is the name of an picture file

\pgfkeys{
  c/.code args={[#1]{#2}}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
  }
\pgfkeys{c={logob}}%Same as \includegraphics{logob} 
% The above code does not work because #1 is not given. How to make it work when optional args are not given?
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pgfkeys{c=[]{logob}}`?

Comment: Take care `\pgfkeys{c=[width=2cm]{logob}}` will blow up badly. Can you see why?

Comment: Since #1 is optional, I'd like `\pgfkeys{c={logob}}`, not `\pgfkeys{c=[]{logob}}` when #1 is not given. So what is the correct way to achieve both `\pgfkeys{c={logob}}` and `\pgfkeys{c=[width=2cm]{logob}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below would work. The key `/c` accepts a single argument, then different forms of `\includegraphics` is called, depending on whether the value of key starts with `[`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  c/.code={%
    \@ifnextchar[%]
      {\includegraphics#1\mykeys@gobble@til@nil}
      {\includegraphics{#1}\mykeys@gobble@til@nil}%
    #1\@nil
  }
}

\long\def\mykeys@gobble@til@nil#1\@nil{}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{c={example-image}}
% Same as \includegraphics{...}

\pgfkeys{c={[width=3cm]{example-image}}}
% Same as \includegraphics[width=3cm]{...}
\end{document}
```